# How to right justify a graphic in a JavaFX TreeCell

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX TreeView/TreeCell that has a button as part of the TreeCell's graphic.  I'd like to get the buttons to be right justified such that they appear as a column near the right edge of the scene, regardless of the level of the tree node or text width.  I've attempted to add a spacer within the HBox that contains the button, but it doesn't appear to affect anything.  Is there a simple way to accomplish what I want, or do I need to resort to something like calculating the space available for the tree cell and setting a preferred size on the HBox?  Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
public class TreeCellAlignment extends Application {

    private static class CustomTreeCell extends TreeCell<String> {
        private HBox box = new HBox(4);

        public CustomTreeCell() {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
            Region spacer = new Region();
            HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
            box.getChildren().addAll(spacer, new Button("X"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(empty ? null : item);
            setGraphic(empty ? null : box);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("root");
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("child"));
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>(root);
        tree.setCellFactory(param -> new CustomTreeCell());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tree, 300, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only way to do it is to manually set `graphicTextGap`, or bind it to a calculation based on the total width. Kinda sucks, but I don't think there is currently a better solution.

Comment: What you want exists ans is called a TreeTableView (available with FX8) : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html